# Selenium Webdriver Code Snippet for broken Links

Tags: python, selenium

I was trying to use the following code snippet to verify if all the links are working or not

```py
links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")
for link in links:
    if requests.head(link.get_attribute('href')).status_code == 200:
        print("valid link")
    else:
        print("Broken Link")
```

It gives me this error message in the console:

`raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'javascript:window.print()'`

Comment: Can I get the URL?

Comment: Looks like some href values doesn't have protocol scheme like  http.Without the http:// part, requests has no idea how to connect to the remote server.

Comment: here is the URL: https://cmsnationaltrainingprogram.cms.gov/?q=help

Comment: You are getting this error as your website has href value as ```javascript:window.print()```. Do you consider href value  ```javascript:window.print()``` as valid link or Broken link?. As per my understanding, we should consider ```javascript:window.print()``` as valid link.

Answer (score 0):

`javascript:window.print()` opens a print dialog, it is totally normal that `requests` has no idea what to do with it. You may want to filter "links" like `javascript:window.print()`, `javascript:alert("something")`.

You probably want to find your links with something more like this:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, *) and not(contains(@href, "#") or contains(@href, "javascript:"))]')
```

This should return all anchors, except the ones which contain `#` or `javascript:` as `href` value ("contain" is a partial match filter).

You may want to finetune the xpath to consider values invalid which do not contain `.` or `/` (relative addresses may be found with no protocol or server url if a [base url is defined](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)).

Comment: it gives me this error :

raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'None': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://None?